# Servlet returning a response to calling Java Program

Tags: java, servlets

iam calling an servlet class "MyServlet" from a my java class program named "MyJavaCode"  as shown below in the MyJavaCode class:

```
URL url = new URL(full_url);
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
in.close();
}
```

MyServlet has some String values which i currently print in the same class like "FileCount" ,"ErrorCount" etc. I need to get these values to the calling program MyJavaCode . How to get this ?
Also i need to know whether the servlets has returned any error using status code. So how to get these values in MyJavaCode class?

Comment: You need to read about how HTTP works. If the servlets is writing to a logger, then what does the HTTP response have to do with that?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis : i mean i need to get the values to the calling program to use those values there.

Comment: Write them to the HTTP response.

Comment: If you're returning text, you need to either know the exact format and parse it. You *should* be returning JSON/etc to make that easier, though, if your servlet is to be used as a service endpoint.

Comment: Is it a query GET parameter or a POST parameter? You may want to consider a higher level client library like Jersey or Apache HttpClient

Comment: @user2684301 the servlet is doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response). here iam doing some processing on files and getting the filecount which passed successfully. I need to send this filecount to my calling program.

Comment: Iam not able to understand how to write the response on reading about it. Can someone explain me clearly with an example?

Comment: `response.getWriter().println("this is what I send as response text");`

Comment: Thanks..How do we read the response from the servlet apart from doing a BufferedReader in java class calling the servlet.. I see lots of performance issues reading this line by line. Is there any efficient way of reading the output from servlet?